# Connection timed out when using doctrine migration (Symfony 5)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to make migration using this command

```
php bin/console make:migration
```

But it returns me this error

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le 
parti connecté n’a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a 
échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas répondu                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
In Exception.php line 18:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu 
convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion 
n’a pas répondu  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In PDOConnection.php line 38:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu 
convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion 
n’a pas répondu
```

So I tried this code to test my database connection

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->getConnection()->connect();
$conn = $em->getConnection();
var_dump($conn->isConnected());
```

The weird thing is that when I put the hostname (@xxxxx:3306), it works and returns ***bool(true)***.
But when I put the IP adress (@xxx.xx.xxx.xx:3306), it returns me ***connection refused***.

Here is my .env file (not a local database)

```
DATABASE_HOST=xxxxx
DATABASE_PORT=3306
DATABASE_USER=user_xxxxx
DATABASE_PWD=pass_xxxxx
DATABASE_NAME=db_xxxxx
DATABASE_URL="mysql://user_xxxxx:pass_xxxxx@xxxxx:3306/db_xxxxx?serverVersion=5.5.68-MariaDB"
```

And here is my doctrine.yaml file

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
    server_version: '5.5.68-MariaDB'
    charset: utf8mb4
    host: '%env(DATABASE_HOST)%'
    port: '%env(DATABASE_PORT)%'
    user: '%env(DATABASE_USER)%'
    password: '%env(DATABASE_PWD)%'
    dbname: '%env(DATABASE_NAME)%'
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

Can someone help me with this error ?

Comment: Are you sure about the format of the serverVersion parameter here? There is doc when you use a mariaDb database here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration Moreover, you don't have to fill the doctrine.yaml parameters like host, port,etc, because they are define by the url parameter

Comment: The request SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%" returns me this : innodb_version = 5.5.61-MariaDB-38.13 / version = 5.5.68-MariaDB

Comment: I don't doubt about it but there is a doctrine specific format here. In the Doctrine doc ->" If you are running a MariaDB database, you should prefix the serverVersion with mariadb- (ex: mariadb-10.2.12)" https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html

Comment: Ok, so I put that mariadb-5.5.68 but sadly does not change something

Comment: Is your user allowed to log in to this distant database? Do you really use "user_", "pass" and "db_" as a prefix or it is here as an exemple?

Comment: I can log in through phpmyadmin so I guess I'm allowed no ? "user_", "pass_" and "db_" are just for exemple yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I was executing this line locally, I don't knew that I needed to do it on the "server side". I'm sorry, I learnt Symfony 4 days ago and I'm trying my best.

```
php bin/console make:migration
```

Now, the question is how I can't get access to my server console ?

Thanks for help